# Cosemisimple Hopf algebra and Krull-Schmidt

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, coalgebras

A **cosemisimple** Hopf algebra is one which is the sum of its cosimple sub-cobalgebras. Is it clear that a comodule of a cosemisimple Hopf algebra always decomposes into irreducible parts? Moreover, will this decomposition obey **Krull-Schmidt**, by which I mean will the type and multiplicity of the irreducible comodules appearing be the same in any decomposition.

I am sure that this should be the case but I can't see how to prove it. One thing that confuses me is the prospect of infinite multiplicity in the case of an infinite dimensional comodule.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question, I think the following definition and theorem settles the answer to the affirmative:

**Definition:** A coalgebra $C$ is called **right cosemisimple** (or **right completely reducible** coalgebra) if the Category $M^C$ is a semisimple Category i.e. if every right $C$-comodule is cosemisimple.

Similarly, **left cosemisimple** coalgebras are defined by the semisimplicity of the Category of left comodules.

**Theorem:** Let $C$ be a coalgebra. The following assertions are equivalent:

1. $C$ is a right cosemisimple coalgebra
2. $C$ is a left cosemisimple coalgebra
3. $C=C_0$
4. Every left (right) rational $C^*$-module is semisimple

where $C_0=Corad(C)$ i.e. the **coradical** of $C$, which is the sum of all its simple subcoalgebras.

For a proof of the above you can see for example [Hopf algebras-an introduction, Dascalescu-Nastasescu-Raianu](https://books.google.gr/books?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&printsec=frontcover&hl=el&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), Ch.3, p.118-119, Theorem 3.1.5. (However this is more or less standard material, you can also find it in Sweedler's book on Hopf algebras, etc).

Now, regarding your second question, I think you can use the above theorem together with the correspondence between $C$-comodules and rational $C^*$-modules to investigate the situation closer.