# Cosemisimple coalgebras and uniqueness of their cosimple decompositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, coalgebras

A coalgebra $C$ is called *cosimple* if it has no subcoalgebras. It is called *cosemisimple* if it is a direct sum of simple coalgebras.

Is this direct sum decomposition unique? Explicitly, can there exist another decomposition into simple coalgebras which are of different isomorphic class or appear with different multiplicities?

Moreover, [n-lab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cosemisimple+coalgebra) says that cosemisimplicity

> is equivalent to saying that every $C$-comodule is a direct sum of simple subcomodules.

Why is this true?

Comment: Discussion about the second question you can find in S.Montgomery 'Hopf Algebras and Their Actions on Rings' - 2.4 and in M.E.Sweedler 'Hopf Algebras' - chapter XIV.

Comment: I think your question is closely related to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756673/cosemisimple-hopf-algebra-and-krull-schmidt/1769896#1769896